# mogrify -monochrome to several Picture

Tags: bash, command-line, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I have some Picture, that I want have in black and white.

I'am in the right folder.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 alex alex  1027 Jan 21 13:07 target-0.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 alex alex  1001 Jan 21 12:17 target-1.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 alex alex   957 Jan 21 12:17 target-2.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 alex alex   982 Jan 21 12:17 target-4.jpg
```

Why do this not work?

```
for i in *.jpg ; do mogrify -monochrome ; done
```

No errors, but no black and white Pictures. When I convert them single `mogrify -monochrome target-0.jpg` it works as expected. Version of imagemagick

```
apt-cache policy imagemagick
imagemagick:
  Installiert:           8:6.8.9.9-5+deb8u6
  Installationskandidat: 8:6.8.9.9-5+deb8u6
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 8:6.8.9.9-5+deb8u6 0
        500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

And

```
env | grep -i shell
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not pass the variable `i` to your `mogrify` command in the for loop. It should be as follows.

```
for i in *.jpg ; do mogrify -monochrome "$i"; done
```

Comment: Saddly not it ends up in like this `for i in *.jpg ; do mogrify -monochrome $[i} ; done 
> `

Comment: Well, `for i in *.jpg ; do mogrify -monochrome ${i} ; done` did work for me. But it is better to double-quote the variable as Kusalananda corrected.

Comment: @Bahamut Have a look at the corrected command. The initial command had a syntax error in it (unbalanced `[` and `}`).

Comment: yes you are right wrong not [ }but this { }work.  I need eye glasses ^^

Comment: Hm...I started the mistake and I already wear eye glasses. =0)

Comment: Thomas can you write your comment  as answer so I can except it? Or edit your first answer?

Comment: Kusalananda already corrected the mistake, thanks for that. So there is no need do adopt the above answer.